# .htaccess rewrite pretty url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect, friendly-url

I'm new to .htaccess coding and I'm finding it way more confusing than html and css. I want to make my url's more seo friendly and just easier for my users. My current code isn't working. I want to make my urls look like my example below. Let me know if it's possible, I'd prefer not to show my id numbers.

example url

http://mobile.mixtapemonkey.com/artist?a=96/2-chainz

solutions I can live with

- .com/2-chainz
- .com/a/2-chainz
- .com/artist/2-chainz

  ```
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+artist\?a=([^&]+)&t=([^\s&]+) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ a/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(\d+)/([^/]+)/?$ artist.php?a=$1&t=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
  ```

Comment: If you want to hide the ID number (96), you'll have to rely on a handler script which parses the title to its corresponding ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you accept the rewrites with the ID in URL, try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /artist\?a=(\d+)/(\S*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ a/%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^a/(\d+)/(.*)/?$ artist.php?a=$1/$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

It'll rewrite the URL: `http://mobile.mixtapemonkey.com/artist?a=96/2-chainz` to: `http://mobile.mixtapemonkey.com/a/96/2-chainz`.